# create row with multiple cells via backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a rather simple backbone view that renders a  tag when iterating through each item in a collection via the _.each function.

```
var SingleView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName:td,
  //other stuff
});
```

I have a view for the collection as well

```
var CollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
//other stuff
this.collection.each(function(model ,i) {
var item = new SingleView({model: model});
 //alert(i);
//maybe in here is where I need logic to wrap a row around a <td> tag ?
 $('.collection').append(item.render().$el);

});
```

Then in the template:

```
<table class = "collection">
<!-- variables to render as html -->
</table>
```

What I'm hoping to do is wrap a given number of items in a table row, or `<tr></tr>`.  It's easy to get one cell/row.  I'm trying to get 2 or 3 or however many cells per row that I want.   I've tried the Jquery wrap feature, and I'm guessing I need some kind of modular division but I'm kind of stuck.   I'm also new to Backbone which is another hurdle.

To clarify - an individual item in the collection should be in each `<td>`, and I'm trying to place > 1 `<td>` in each row.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. What's expected and what are your results instead? Fyi `$(...)` within a view is a bad habit, you should narrow down to the view using `this.$(...)`

Comment: What I'm trying to do is have a way to control the number of model instances that populate a row in a table, so for example `<tr><td>model 1 view</td><td>model 2 view</td></tr>` or maybe  `<tr><td>model 1 view</td><td>model 2 view</td><td>model 3 view</td></tr>`

Comment: So each row can have a variable column count? You know that the table will look odd and is perhaps badly formatted if you do so? How do you expect to align the columns of each row when the count differs? What should control when a new row starts? _If exactly this is your question you may want to reformulate your question and ask how to change the implementation away from your approach (if and only if you're open to other proposals)._

Comment: no - each row would have the same # of columns.  I was looking for a generic solution to set the number of columns I want and then go from there :)

Comment: So each N columns (`currentModelndex % N`) a new `tr` element should be rendered and the following models should be appended to it? GEneric means you can specify either "2" or "5" for different instances and the same collection would render 10 models as  2 columns in 5 rows or 5 columns in 2 rows?

Comment: Yes - exactly.  I've been fiddling around with modular division but haven't quite worked it out.

Comment: Then please - for god's sake - edit your question and add this.

Comment: Finally voted for close/unclear. You talked about "`generic solution to set the number of columns`" columns and said "`I've been fiddling around with modular division but haven't quite worked it out`". You did not edit your question. It's not well formatted, only clear after reading a bunch of comments and finally you accept an answer that does not take your *number of columns* thing into account. I'm baffled.

Comment: ok - nonetheless the user who provided the accepted answer seemed to understand the question, and the implementation absolutely works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to create a working example as close to your explanation as possible. It renders a collection as table cells, and I think you can go from there.

Basically, you shouldn't manually wrap your `td`'s in a `tr` tag. Create instances of `TrView` and `TdView` respectively, depending on the flow of your data. Append `tr` to `table`, and `td` to `tr`.

Also you might want to look at CollectionView implemented in Marionette:
http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.3/marionette.collectionview.html

Example #1:

```js
var collection = new Backbone.Collection([
  { title: 'Item 1' },
  { title: 'Item 2' },
  { title: 'Item 3' }
]);

var TableView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: "table",
  className: "collection",
  render: function(){
    var rowView = new RowView({ collection: collection });
    this.$el.html( rowView.render().el );
    return this;
  }
});

var RowView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: "tr",
  render: function(){
    this.collection.each(this.appendItem, this);
    return this;
  },
  appendItem: function(model){
    var tdView = new TdView({ model:model });
    this.$el.append( tdView.render().el );
  }
});

var TdView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: "td",
  render: function(){
    this.$el.text( this.model.get('title') );
    return this;
  }
});

var tableView = new TableView();
tableView.render().$el.appendTo(document.body);
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid steelblue;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid brown;
  padding: 3px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js'></script>
<script src='http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js'></script>
<script src='http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js'></script>
```

Example #2:

```js
var collection = new Backbone.Collection([
  { title: 'Item 1' },
  { title: 'Item 2' },
  { title: 'Item 3' },
  { title: 'Item 4' },
  { title: 'Item 5' },
  { title: 'Item 6' }
]);

var TableView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: "table",
  className: "collection",
  initialize: function(o){
    this.maxItemsInRow = o.maxItemsInRow? o.maxItemsInRow: 3;
  },
  render: function(){
    this.collection.each(this.addItem, this);
    return this;
  },
  addRow: function(){
    var rowView = new RowView({ collection: collection });
    rowView.$el.appendTo( this.el );
    this.currentRow = rowView;
    this.currentRowItemsLength = 0;
  },
  addItem: function(model){
    if( typeof this.currentRow === 'undefined') {
      this.addRow();
    }
    this.currentRow.addItem(model);
    this.currentRowItemsLength++;
    if(this.currentRowItemsLength >= this.maxItemsInRow){
      this.currentRow = undefined;
    }
  }
});

var RowView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: "tr",
  addItem: function(model){
    var tdView = new TdView({ model:model });
    this.$el.append( tdView.render().el );
  }
});

var TdView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: "td",
  render: function(){
    this.$el.text( this.model.get('title') );
    return this;
  }
});

var tableView = new TableView({ collection: collection, maxItemsInRow: 3 });
tableView.render().$el.appendTo(document.body);
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid steelblue;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid brown;
  padding: 3px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js'></script>
<script src='http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js'></script>
<script src='http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js'></script>
```

Comment: I've tried an approach like this - thanks.  So where I'm stuck is let's say the collection has 6 models and I want 2 rows in the table with 3 cells each.   I need the view to somehow know when to stop adding cells to each row, and when to start a new row.

Comment: You may program your TableView to accept items directly and dynamically append a new TrView, then append the items to that TrView unless they are within the defined quantity, then the Table would append another Tr and continue adding items to the new row, and so on.

Comment: I've updated my answer with second example that shows how you can do that.

Comment: thanks!!!  I've made a few tweaks since I'm dealing with an API to fetch my collection.  Very nice approach - I'm seeing how flexible backbone (ha ha) is - it takes some getting used to.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/9mjcmgpo/

```
var SingleView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'tr',
  template: _.template('<td><%=name%></td><td><%=age%></td><td><%=sex%></td>'),
  render: function() {
      this.$el.append(this.template(this.model.toJSON()))
      return this
  }
});

var CollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
      template: _.template('<tr><th>name</th><th>age</th><th>sex</th></tr>'),
    initialize: function() {
        this.$el = $('.collection');
        this.el = this.$el[0];

        // sudo collection
        this.collection = new Backbone.Collection();
        this.collection.add({'name': 'test1', 'sex': 'f', age: 21});
        this.collection.add({'name': 'test2', 'sex': 'o', age: 25});
        this.collection.add({'name': 'test3', 'sex': 'm', age: 26});

        // hack
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template());
        this.collection.each(_.bind(function(model) {
            var item = new SingleView({model: model});
            this.$el.append(item.render().$el);
        }, this));
        return this;
    }
});

new CollectionView()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following. I have hard coded `3` as the number of rows. You can use variable number by passing it to the view if necessary.

```js
var collection = new Backbone.Collection([{
  title: 'Item 1'
}, {
  title: 'Item 2'
}, {
  title: 'Item 3'
}, {
  title: 'Item 4'
}, {
  title: 'Item 5'
}]);

var TdView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: "td",
  initialize: function() {
    this.render();
  },
  render: function() {
    this.$el.text(this.model.get('title'));
    return this;
  }
});

var TableView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: "table",
  className: "collection",
  initialize: function() {
    this.render();
  },
  render: function() {
    var $tr = $('<tr/>');
    var count = 1;
    this.collection.each(function(model, i) {
      if ((i / 3) >= count) { // end of current row
        this.$el.append($tr); //append current row
        $tr = $('<tr/>'); // create new row
        count = this.$el.find('tr').length + 1; // refresh counter
      }
      $tr.append(new TdView({ // append td to current row
        model: model
      }).el);
    }, this);
    this.$el.append($tr); // append final row 
    return this;
  }
});


var tableView = new TableView({
  collection: collection
});
tableView.$el.appendTo('body');
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid steelblue;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid brown;
  padding: 3px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js'></script>
<script src='http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js'></script>
<script src='http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js'></script>
```